Internal Server Error (500) When Authenticating with MongoDB Atlas in Ballerina

I'm encountering an internal server error (500) while trying to authenticate with MongoDB Atlas

here's the error massage I am receiving.
{
"timestamp": "2024-10-08T03:07:38.336267800Z",
"status": 500,
"reason": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, userName='ballerina', source='Users', password=, mechanismProperties=}",
"path": "/customers",
"method": "GET"
}

This is my code block


import ballerina/http;
import ballerinax/mongodb;
import ballerina/io;

// MongoDB configuration...
configurable string host = "localhost";
configurable int port = 27017;
configurable string username = ?;
configurable string password = ?;
configurable string database = ?;

final mongodb:Client mongoDb = check new (
    {
        connection: {
        serverAddress: {
            host,
            port
        },
        auth: <mongodb:ScramSha256AuthCredential>{
            username,
            password,
            database
        }
    }
    }
);

service on new http:Listener(9091) {
    private final mongodb:Database db;

    function init() returns error? {
        io:println("Connecting to database...");
        self.db = check mongoDb->getDatabase("Users");
        io:println("Connected to database.");
    }

    // Resource for the root path
    resource function get root() returns string {
        return "Welcome to the VitaCam backend!";
    }

    // Resource for customers
    resource function get customers() returns Customer | error {
        io:println("Fetching a single customer...");
        mongodb:Collection customersCollection = check self.db->getCollection("VitaCam_Auth");
        
        // Use findOne to retrieve a single document for testing
        Customer? customer = check customersCollection->findOne({});
        if (customer is ()) {
            return error("No customer found");
        }
        return customer;
    }
}

type Customer record {| 
    string id; 
    string name; 
    string email; 
    string address; 
    string contactNumber; 
|};

I am using Ballerina to connect to MongoDB Atlas.
My connection configuration is as follows:
Username: ballerina
Database: Users
I made a GET request to /customers.
Expected Behavior:

I expect to successfully authenticate and retrieve data from the /customers endpoint.

Actual Behavior:

I receive a 500 Internal Server Error during authentication.


Are you sure, the user is crated in database Users? Usually they are created in admin database.

yeah, I double-checked with that admin database also

This error normally happen when we try to connect with incorrect pasword or incorrect authentication db

In MongoDB, the authentication is done via the admin database. In your case, when authenticating, try to change the database to admin, and then when retrieving the customers, use the Users database.
